# How To Use One Device Between Developers

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

For a specific app we would like to share one iPad between developers but we are developing on multiple macs.

When we try to do this the scenario we have is that we have multiple development macs and various versions of the app on those macs.  We want to install the app for testing onto one iPad from Xcode on any of the available macs.

Doing this we have run into problems with provisioning profiles where we have to transfer the developer profile onto each of the macs. Log in to the member centre and disable the device and reenable it etc.  The fun of provisioning profiles never ceases to amaze me.

Is there an easier way that we can just connect the iPad to any of the machines and install the app from Xcode with no hassle with profiles?

Comment: Do you have enterprise account?

Answer (score 2):

We have mutiple test devices and all our machines use the same developer certificate, just export the public and private key of the certificate on the machine that requested the certificate.

Then just use the same profile on all machines, You can now just connect any device to the machine how share the certificate and it will work.

You can let Xcode handle the certificates and profiles, just create account for each developers and add the devices to to the profile from Xcode. Every user wil have there own certificate and profiles, but the devices can be shared by all.

Comment: doesnt it override the same app if they use same profile and bundle identifier?  I guess they want to see same app's different versions on the device right?

Comment: Yes that's one of the reasons. Another is we want less issues with provisioning profiles when we share devices. Ideally we just want to plug in, install app & test the app version.

Comment: Well if you want to install the same app but not override the other developers app you will need different bundles identifiers for the apps. This will also mean different profiles, but not different certificates. You also create a generic profile ( use a * as the bundle ID). You will not have all the options you get it a specific profile (push messaging, ...) but it will be easy to work with. Also most developer profiles are already generic (*).